# Is there a VBA syntax that will automatically pick up the range of cells that are populated each time macro is ran?

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to write a macro that creates a random number generator of 50values to use for a sample size for a confidence interval.  Can someone please guide me to a syntax that will automatically know the range of cells that are populated?  The amount of data will be different for each project.  So I need the macro to know how many cells are populated and the different ranges every time.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Range of cells that are populated where? On the current ActiveSheet, or somewhere else? You'll need to be a bit more specific.

Comment: Are you looking to find the last row in the spreadsheet, in order to append the next 50 values to it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, was in a meeting. Im an intern and im trying to dumb down the process of finding confidence intervals for my manager by writing a macro in excel. Lets say that I want to import about 1000 datasets into column one each cell containing an atomic value. I want to right a macro that will randomly select 50 of those cells. I want the macro to know exactly how many of those cells are populated because the amount of data sets will very each time when running the macro. My question is, what keyword or syntax would I use to do this.

Comment: This has been asked many many times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Worksheet.UsedRange` method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215923(v=office.11).aspx

To answer your comment, you can use something like this:

```
Public Sub getStuff()
    Dim aRange As Excel.Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set aRange = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    End With

    Debug.Print aRange.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: You are awesome! One more question for you. This is highliting all colums that are populated.  How would I do this for just the column A beginning with row 2?